# Bash create parameter named array within function

Tags: bash, array, function, declare

I'm attempting to write a function that writes arrays with a name that's passed in. Given the following bash function:

```
function writeToArray {
    local name="$1"
    echo "$name"
    declare -a "$name"
    ${name[0]}="does this work?"      
}
```

Running like this:

```
writeToArray $("test")
```

I get two errors:

```
bash: declare: `': not a valid identifier
=does this work?: command not found
```

I am expecting to be able to do this:

```
writeToArray $("test")
for item in "${test[@]}"; do
        echo "item"
        echo "$item"
done
```

This should print:

```
item
does this work?
```

How could I properly configure this to write the array (named `test` in the example, such that this array named `test` is readable outside the function)?

Comment: @EdMorton Updated, I'm aiming to create an array called "test" that contains the string "does this work?" as its first element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd use a nameref for that:

```
writeToArray() {
    local -n writeToArray_name="$1"
    writeToArray_name[0]="does this work?"      
}
```

Testing:

```
bash-5.0$ test[123]=qwe
bash-5.0$ writeToArray test
bash-5.0$ typeset -p test
declare -a test=([0]="does this work?" [123]="qwe")
```

With older versions of `bash` which didn't have namerefs yet, you could use `eval`:

```
writeToArray() {
  eval "$1[0]='does this work?'"
}
```

When `writeToArray` is invoked with `test` as argument, `eval` is passed `test[0]='does this work?'` as argument, and that in turns is `eval`uated as code in the shell language where it assigns `does this work?` to the element of index 0 of the `test` array (also works for associative array; scalar variables are converted to arrays).

Note that `$("test")` is syntax to capture and expand the output of `test` command and split+glob it when in list context. `test` (aka `[`) produces no output when not passed any argument), so `$("test")` expands to the empty string and split+glob gives you nothing at all out of it.

Here, it's the *name* of your variable that you want to pass to `writeToArray`, so `test`, not its contents (`"$test"`) nor the output of a command by the same name (`"$(test)"`) let alone the output of a command by the same name subject to split+glob as with your `$("test")` attempt.

Comment: Great answer, I'd become confused over use of `$(...)`. I also noted your answer worked for `writeToArray "test"` (with quotation marks).

Comment: @Lee, would also work with `"writeToArray" 'te'"st"`. Quotes in shells are to prevent some characters to be treated specially (and double quotes also prevent split+glob which is why you almost always want quotes around variable expansions), but here none of the characters in `writeToArray` or `test` are special to the shell so quoting is not needed. The only special characters are space (used to delimit arguments to that command) and newline used to delimit that command.